# Overpass query to find POI in a specific postalcode

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, overpass-api

I am facing a challenge in crafting an overpass query to identify points of interest (POIs) such as hospitals and schools within a specific zipcode. Despite my attempts with the following query:

```
[out:json];
(
  node["amenity"="hospital"](34.0522,-118.2437,34.0622,-118.2337)["postal_code"="90005"];
  node["amenity"="hospital"](34.0485,-118.2923,34.0585,-118.2823)["postal_code"="90006"];
  node["amenity"="hospital"](34.0122,-118.3365,34.0222,-118.3265)["postal_code"="90008"];
);

out center;
```

It seems to be ineffective for my purpose. I would appreciate assistance in refining this query or exploring alternative approaches to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "ineffective for my purpose"?  Does it work, or doesn't it?  What happens?

Comment: That's not very helpful.  What DOES happen?

Comment: The overpass query yields:

```json
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.61.5 4133829e",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2024-02-22T07:59:00Z",
    "copyright": "Data from www.openstreetmap.org, available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": []
}
```

Initially, I thought it lacked data, so I broadened the search for all amenities, even with extra locations. However, results persistently show no relevant amenities data. Seeking advice to resolve or explore alternatives.  @TimRoberts

Comment: Your bounding rectangle is only 0.6 miles square.  Are you sure there's a hospital in there?

Comment: I appreciate you informing me that my query only encompasses a distance of 0.6 miles, as you mentioned.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to use the Overpass API for a large area, rather than specifying individual coordinates? My current query covers a broad region like this:

```[out:json];(
  way[amenity=school](minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon);
  way[amenity=gym](minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon);
  way[amenity=casino](minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon);
  way[amenity=restaurant](minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon);
);out center;```

Any streamlined approach involving directly providing the zipcode would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like query by postal code is not available everywhere.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231958/query-overpass-turbo-for-postal-code-boundaries